# mandatory property in return object of an EF linq query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

In my application, i have several linq queries who must return the same object type with the same properties in the same order.
So, how can i define mandatory properties of a return object ?

Queries are like this :

```
from foo in bar
select new myobject {
  myprop1 = foo.x, //This one must be filled everytime
  myprop2 = foo.y
}
```

Thank's by advance !

Comment: You want that the `myprop1` is filled automaticaly?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming foo.x is a nullable integer, how about something like

from foo in bar
select new myobject {

myprop1 = foo.x ==null ? 0 : foo.x ,

myprop2 = foo.y
}

Comment: The problem is that i want to allow to develop others queries who return the same object type and oblige the developer to fill some properties everytime.